# videocapture window not closing - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Am trying to capture a live video using my webcam.
 And the code i learnt from the internet works like a charm.
 But there's an issue after i updated my opencv to 4.2.0 that the videoCapture window is not at all closing no matter how many times i try.

**Source Code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv.flip(frame,1)
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Click the window that is displaying the image (not the Terminal running the script) and press `q`.

Comment: Yeah q works but the close option is not. Why?

Comment: Somehow opencv cannot understand the window close event directly, always use the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following at the end of the while loop to detect if the window was closed and terminate the loop:

```py
    if cv.getWindowProperty('frame', cv.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
        break
```

The `getWindowProperty` will return 0 if the window `frame` no longer exists.

Comment: THIS.. I've been looking for an answer for a while as all sorts of suggestions. But this does 100% of the time kill the loop and doesn't hang the program on exit. Thank you @naszy